# Cron doesn't send email (while script does)

Tags: cron, mail

I have a simple script to send a back-up of my db to email:

```
#!/bin/sh

timestamp=$(date '+%d-%m-%Y@%H:%M')

mysqldump -u root  -pPASSWORD DBNAME | gzip > /tmp/database_$timestamp.sql.gz

mutt -s "backup from DBNAME | $timestamp" my.g.mail@gmail.com  -a /tmp/database_$timestamp.sql.gz < /opt/message.txt

rm /tmp/database_$timestamp.sql.gz
```

saved in /opt/db_backup.sh

when I run

```
. /opt/db_backup.sh
```

I SUCCESSFULLY got email on my gmail!!!

/var/log/mail.log :

> - Jan 24 00:30:34 ip-173-32-37-92 postfix/pickup[1483]: 85308320E:    uid=1000 from=
> - Jan 24 00:30:34 ip-173-32-37-92 postfix/cleanup[1884]: 85308320E:    message-id=<**20180124003034.GA1873@vista9.ru**>
> - Jan 24 00:30:34 ip-173-32-37-92 postfix/qmgr[1484]: 85308320E:    from=, size=323952, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
> - Jan 24 00:30:34 ip-173-32-37-92 postfix/smtp[1887]: connect to    **gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com**[2a00:1450:400c:c04::1a]:25: Network is
>     unreachable
> - Jan 24 00:30:35 ip-173-32-37-92 postfix/smtp[1887]: 85308320E:    to=<**my.g.mail@gmail.com**>,
>     relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.203.27]:25, $
> - Jan 24 00:30:35 ip-173-32-37-92 postfix/qmgr[1484]: 85308320E:    removed

I've created a cron task: `crontab -e`

```
*/1 * * * * /opt/db_backup.sh
```

so after a minute CRON worked:

> - Jan 24 00:57:01 ip-173-32-37-92 CRON[2034]: (ubuntu) CMD    (/opt/db_backup.sh)

and ... I GOT NO EMAIL :(...

/var/log/mail.log :

> - Jan 24 01:02:02 ip-173-32-37-92 postfix/pickup[1483]: 01DC83238:    uid=1000 from=
> - Jan 24 01:02:02 ip-173-32-37-92 postfix/cleanup[2038]: 01DC83238:    message-id=20180124010202.01DC83238@**ip-173-32-37-92.eu-central-1.compute.internal**
> - Jan 24 01:02:02 ip-173-32-37-92 postfix/qmgr[1484]: 01DC83238:    from=<**ubuntu@vista9.ru**>, size=674, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
> - Jan 24 01:02:32 ip-173-32-37-92 postfix/smtp[2040]: connect to    **vista9.ru**[81.177.141.15]:25: Connection timed out
> - Jan 24 01:02:32 ip-173-32-37-92 postfix/smtp[2040]: 01DC83238:    to=<**ubuntu@vista9.ru**>, orig_to=, relay=none, delay=30, 
>     delays=0.01/0/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to vista9.ru[81.177.141.15]:25: Connection timed out)

my /etc/mailname:

> vista9.ru

What am I doing wrong?

thank you!

Comment: Is `/opt/db_backup.sh` actually executable? (note: `. /opt/db_backup.sh` would have *sourced* rather than *run* it)

Comment: hm... I am new into server stuff. How to check it? (but, as I wrote - it sends an email to my gmail)

Comment: `ls -l /opt/db_backup.sh`

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 293 Jan 24 01:48 /opt/db_backup.sh  --------so what does it mean?

Comment: That means it's **r**eadable but not executable - you can make it executable with `sudo chmod +x /opt/db_backup.sh`

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! (a little problem though - I set it to send email every minute and it does, but  really I get an email only once in 3 tries - have you encountered this before?)

Comment: you also may answer here and I accept your post as answer:)

Comment: @steeldriver Good on you spotting `./` vs `. /`